# BASH - Comparing two files and redirecting the output to something readable

Tags: linux, bash, diff

I need to run a comparison on two files on a server and have that output include headers, or some other indication, as to where that difference is.

The script currently runs a list of commands and creates a file based on the output. The output is something similar to this:

```
Device 1
Register A value1
Register B value2
Register C value4
...
Register H value5
Device 2
Register A value1
Register B value2
Register C value4
...
Register H value5
```

Every night at midnight, cron will run this script and create a second file with the current devices and their register settings, so I can compare the previous days registers - currently using:

```
diff -u file1.txt file2.txt > filediff.txt
```

if the filediff.txt is empty, it deletes the diff, and moves file1.txt to file2.txt and deletes file1.txt, so I'm left with only file1.txt.

If the filediff.txt file is NOT empty, I get an output similar to the following:

```
-Register B value2
+Register B value3
```

The problem is this: Due to the length of the diff output, I lose the Device name that has the differences, unless that difference is close to a Device name. Is there a flag I can add to the diff command, or a different way to check the differences between the two files, that would include more, or all, of the register values so I can grab the Device name and the register changes (old and new) so I can put those into a text file for reporting:

```
Device 1
Old Register R value18
New Register R value23
```

Comment: to make sure that the diff worked, make sure that this echoes non-zero: `diff -u <original> <new>; echo $?`

Comment: you could probably do something like `comm file1 file 2| awk '{#code to fix formatting}' `. Do the `comm` stuff first to understand how that output works. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just a though to it, what about a post processing with awk that would look like

```
diff -u file1.txt file2.txt | \
    awk -F ' ' '( DEVICE_VAR ~ "" && $1 == "Device"){print DEVICE_VAR "\nOld " FILE1_VAR "\nNew " FILE2_VAR; FILE1_VAR = ""; FILE2_VAR = ""}
                ( $1 == "Device"){DEVICE_VAR = $0} 
                ( $1 == "-Register"){FILE1_VAR = FILE1_VAR " | " $0 } 
                ( $1 == "+Register"){FILE2_VAR = FILE2_VAR " | " $0 }
                END {print DEVICE_VAR "\nOld " FILE1_VAR "\nNew " FILE2_VAR}'
```

file1.txt:

```
Device 1
Register A value1
Register B value2
Register C value4
Device 2
Register A value1
Register B value2
Register C value4
```

file2.txt:

```
Device 1
Register A value6
Register B value7
Register C value8
Device 2
Register A value4
Register B value4
Register C value6
```

Output:

```
Old 
New 
 Device 1
Old  | -Register A value1 | -Register B value2 | -Register C value4
New  | +Register A value6 | +Register B value7 | +Register C value8
 Device 2
Old  | -Register A value1 | -Register B value2 | -Register C value4
New  | +Register A value4 | +Register B value4 | +Register C value6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `-C <n>` to `diff` to get n lines of context either side of the changes.  Unfortunately this is incompatible with the unified diff format `-u`, so you'll have to deal with differently formatted diffs.

E.g. to get 5 lines of context above and below each change:

```
diff -C 5 file1.txt file2.txt > filediff.txt
```

---

*Side note:  If you were dealing with [c](/questions/tagged/c) code, then the `-p` flag is tremendously useful - For each diff chunk it gives you the name of the [c](/questions/tagged/c) function that the change is in.  Its not 100% accurate, but is very useful when quickly visually scanning diffs.  I would assume this works for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) as well, though I haven't tried.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty complicated solution:

```
$ cat file1.txt
Device 1
Register A yesterdays_value1
Register B yesterdays_value2
Register C yesterdays_value4
...
Register H yesterdays_value5
Device 2
Register A yesterdays_value1
Register B yesterdays_value2
Register C yesterdays_value4
...
Register H yesterdays_value5

$ cat file2.txt
Device 1
Register A yesterdays_value1
Register B yesterdays_value2
Register C todays_value44
...
Register H yesterdays_value5
Device 2
Register A yesterdays_value1
Register B todays_value22
Register C yesterdays_value4
...
Register H yesterdays_value5

$ comm <(cat -n file1.txt) <(cat -n file2.txt) |  awk '
    function print_clean(prefix) {
        sub(/^[[:space:]]+[0-9]+\t/, prefix) 
        print
    }
    /^\t\t/ {if (/Device/) print_clean(""); next} 
    /^\t/   {print_clean("New "); next} 
            {print_clean("Old ")}
'
Device 1
New Register C todays_value44
Old Register C yesterdays_value4
Device 2
New Register B todays_value22
Old Register B yesterdays_value2
```

Notes:

- `comm` requires it's input files to be sorted. A way to make any file sorted without rearranging the lines is to prefix the line with its line number. Hence the `cat -n` process substitutions.
- `comm` outputs common lines with 2 leading tabs, lines only in file2 with 1 leading tab and lines only in file1 with no leading tabs. Hence the awk patterns.

A better test to see if there is a diff would be to use `diff -q`

```
if diff -q file1.txt file2.txt; then
    echo no diff
fi
```